# Plot Count from Coordinates of Brooklyn

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap, r-sp, choropleth

I am trying to create a similar plot to below with coordinates:

[image]

My dataset contains coordinates of Brooklyn. Here is an example:

```
coordinates<-data.frame(lat,lon)

head(coordinates)

       lat       lon    Count
1 40.61847 -74.02123       50
2 40.71348 -73.96551      100
3 40.69948 -73.96104      102 
4 40.70377 -73.93116      150
5 40.67859 -73.99049       80
6 40.71234 -73.92416      200
```

What is the best way to plot this sort of data so that it becomes a heat map like above?

For some context on how I made the first one, I used this tutorial: https://towardsdatascience.com/tutorial-data-wrangling-and-mapping-in-r-ec828acc8073

Answer (score 0):

Its clear that they have opened shape file and plotted them with var = "Building_Count". Your problem is half way similar to this. As per my under standing you have two thing one shapefile of Brooklyn and another dataframe which has lat long and some value(count). you have to  follow the steps below

1. Open Shape file
2. Read data frame
3. For each part of shape file find how many points lie inside polygon boundary. (use inpolygon function)
4. Sum the values (counts). For example, lets say the shapefile has 500 polygons. then for first poly you get 10 points inside the polygon. Then you can take sum over "count" variable for those 10 points
5. Now you will have new data set of same length of shapefile which you can plot.